# JavaFX BarChart implementation - why use StackPanes for bars?

Tags: java, charts, javafx, javafx-8

I have been looking quite deeply at the implementations of the charts in JavaFX as of late and noticed that in [BarChart.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9-dev/rt/file/e4b36fdb7c26/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/chart/BarChart.java), StackPanes are used for the individual bars, like so:

```
bar = new StackPane();
item.setNode(bar);
bar.getStyleClass().addAll("chart-bar", "series" + seriesIndex, "data" + itemIndex);
```

Later (in `layoutPlotChildren(...)`):

```
bar.resizeRelocate(xPos, bottom, barWidth, top - bottom);
```

It seems to me that a more logical choice would be to use a Rectangle, especially since the [JavaFX Peformance Tips and Tricks](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Performance+Tips+and+Tricks) states that using shape classes (even if they have to be re-created because they are not directly resizable is faster than using a Region/Pane).

The main reason I am asking this question is because I have a custom chart implementation (a candle stick chart) that uses Rectangles for the candles, and I want the bars to be styled the same way. Making a style class for a Rectangle uses different CSS attributes (`-fx-fill`, `-fx-smooth`, `-fx-stroke`, etc.) whereas a Region/Pane uses `-fx-background-color`, `-fx-border-color` and doesn't even have the option of specifying `-fx-smooth` so I can not use one main style class for the candles AND the bars.

The fact that BarChart uses StackPane's for bars leaves me with a couple questions:

- Why? Is it for some weird performance reason that I do not understand?
- Is the choice arbitrary and would another implementation that is roughly the same but uses Rectangles be just as good?
- The color of the bars in BarChart are specified with the `-fx-bar-fill` attribute (which is undocumented in the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)) but furthermore I can not find anywhere in the OpenJFX source where this attribute is specified and looked for, how does this actually work?
- In the CandleStickChart implementation in Ensemble8 [Candle.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9-dev/rt/file/e4b36fdb7c26/apps/samples/Ensemble8/src/samples/java/ensemble/samples/charts/candlestick/Candle.java) the individual candles (very similar to the bars of a BarChart) are actually Groups containing a Line for the wick and a Region for the candle itself. This is different than my personal implementation and different from the BarChart implementation as well - again is this choice arbitrary or are there good reasons for using these classes as opposed to 2 Rectangles or one Rectangle and 1 Line, say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why use StackPanes for bars?

I don't have any knowledge of the minds of the JavaFX team, but I suspect that the choice of because of the CSS support. Because `StackPane` inherits from [`Region`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region), it supports a very rich set of styleable properties, such as the background, border, and even shape. So in a `BarChart`, you could set arbitrary background images on the bars just using an external style sheet, for example. By contrast, [`Shape`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#shape) support a much more limited set of styleable properties. Using a `StackPane` rather than a `Region` directly would allow, in theory anyway, the possibility of adding further nodes to the bar, though I think any such code would be pretty ugly.

> The color of the bars in BarChart are specified with the -fx-bar-fill
>   attribute...  how does this actually work?

`-fx-bar-fill` is a [looked-up color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) that is defined in the default stylesheet, [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u40/rt/file/298ec4ec6b35/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css). In general, documentation for the default style sheet is poor: there is no real way to know what looked-up colors are defined for which node types apart from looking at the source code linked above (though, in fairness, it's hard to see what any such documentation might look like in any form that carried the right information and was any more accessible than the css file anyway).

> In the CandleStickChart implementation in Ensemble8...  again is this
>   choice arbitrary or are there good reasons for using these classes as
>   opposed to 2 Rectangles or one Rectangle and 1 Line, say.

Given that a candlestick chart node looks like a line and a rectangle, using a `Group` containing a line and something else makes sense. If you accept the argument about CSS for the bar chart, using a `Region` or `Region` subclass of some kind makes sense to me.

Comment: So if those more advanced styling features are not necessary, because I simply want a colored bar with a sharp (non-smooth) border - using a Shape (e.g. Rectangle) instead of a Region would be preferable? Also about `-fx-bar-fill`, I meant more where is it in the OpenJFX source code? Yes it is in modena.css, but how does the BarChart implementation know to look for that attribute specifically?

Comment: As an aside and not directly related to the question or answer: "what any such documentation might look like in any form that carried the right information and was any more accessible than the css file anyway" -->  I think such documentation would look something like [a ZK style guide component definition](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Style%20Guide/XUL%20Component%20Specification/Listheader/Default).

Comment: I am very interested in the performance characteristics and implications of choosing a Pane/Region versus a Shape (especially if the bars/candles are re-drawn quite frequently).

Comment: @brcolow modena.css defines the `-fx-background-color` for `.chart-bar` (the style class for the bar represented by the `StackPane`) as a linear gradient, defined in terms of the looked-up color `-fx-bar-fill`. (This is on the line immediately after the default definition of `-fx-bar-fill`.) `-fx-background-color` is linked to a property of `Background` in the `Background` class (and is well-documented in the CSS documentation). As for performance, it seems reasonable that a `Shape` would be less expensive than a `Region`, but I haven't really tested that assumption.

Comment: Thank you for the `fx-bar-fill` explanation - what would be the best way to test different implementations? Is there a good way to benchmark such things?

Comment: @jewelsea I'm trying to decide if something like that would really give me the information I need when I'm designing a stylesheet, but I guess something like that could be made to work quite well. Of course, it would also need a tool to generate the docs from the CSS directly (equivalent to javadoc), else you'd have to rely on the programmers to update the documentation, which just wouldn't happen...

Comment: @brcolow I really have to defer to others for "best ways to benchmark". Performance testing something built on a complex framework is notoriously difficult and performance is probably quite dependent on the use case.

Comment: I will just have to stick with the basics, then. Less re-drawing on less nodes.